# Does the shear modulus of silicate minerals vary significantly with changes in P and T?

Tags: geophysics, thermodynamics

I know that the bulk modulus, K, varies with pressure and temperature for silicate minerals and liquids, but what about the shear modulus? If so, is the change drastic for changes from standard temperature and pressure to mantle conditions?

Comment: Can you state explicitly what you mean by K, P, T and SPT?  Cheers

Comment: I changed it in the body of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick Google Scholar [search](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=shear%20modulus%20pressure%20olivine&btnG=Search&as_sdt=800000000001&as_sdtp=on) for the most studied mantle mineral leads to [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0012-821X(98)00063-6), with this in the abstract:

> The shear elastic moduli exhibit non-linear pressure dependencies.

So the answer is yes. As for the magnitude and drastic changes, you will have to do some reading.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. I'm going to keep the question open for a day or so to see if anyone else has anything to offer.